# How to ignore third finger tapping when two fingers are resting on the touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

On my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, resting two fingers on the touchpad and tapping with a third is registered as a three finger tap, while resting a single finger on the touchpad and tapping with another is not registered as a two finger tab.

Apart from the obvious inconsistency, it causes a lot of accidental three finger taps for me, especially when scrolling long websites with two fingers, which in turn opens random new tabs or pastes the clipboard into random text fields.

Is it possible to teach my laptop to ignore two fingers resting + a third finger tapping, similarly to how it ignores one finger resting + a second finger tapping?